# Inserting CSS with a Firefox Extension

Tags: javascript, css, firefox-addon

I'm building a Firefox extension that adds HTML elements to certain pages of a website.  I want to have it insert a custom CSS file to style those elements.  It works if I insert  tags with the CSS right on the page, but that's a less than ideal solution.

Is there anyway to get it to load and parse a CSS file, as if I used the  tag in the header, or am I stuck inlining it somehow?

Comment: Firefox Extension Developers Toolbar lets you "Add User Style Sheet" within CSS menu entry and applies styles immediately to the page loaded. This seems to be the functionality you want. Maybe you can sneek there. https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/60

Comment: If you inline it, then the browser will automatically... load and parse it. I don't see the problem with that approach, if it's giving you the desired effect. By the way this is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731736/how-can-a-firefox-extension-inject-a-local-css-file-into-a-webpage

Answer (score 19, accepted):

chrome:// won't work because the page you are inserting into isn't allowed to access files outside of it's domain (including chrome URIs). This is true even you are the one inserting the link, because the link is still executed in the context of the target page. Instead you have two options:

You can define a resource protocol alias in your manifest and then use a resource URI to access the CSS. For example, the following chrome.manifest will allow you to insert the css as `resource://myextresource/myfile.css`:
`content   myext   content/`
`resource  myextresource   content/css/`
See [MDN Chrome registration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/chrome_registration) for more info. Also see [How can a Firefox extension inject a local css file into a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731736/how-can-a-firefox-extension-inject-a-local-css-file-into-a-webpage) for a similar question.

Or, you can add the CSS as a USER_SHEET using the following. This will make your CSS available across all pages, so be sure you use very unique selectors. One caveat with this approach is that the page CSS has precedence over user sheets. You can use !important to override that, but the page CSS can still trump you if it uses !important as well.

```
var sss = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/content/style-sheet-service;1"]
    .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIStyleSheetService);
var ios = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"]
    .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService);
var uri = ios.newURI(url, null, null);
sss.loadAndRegisterSheet(uri, sss.USER_SHEET);
```

Comment: What is `url` in `var uri = ios.newURI(url, null, null);`. What I want to actually accomplish is to insert jquery UI custom css in a particular page. Will I be able to do it using the second option that you have suggested? Can I do it using FF addon builder (without using the SDK)??

Comment: url is the path to a local CSS file. I believe you can use resource://, chrome://, file:// for it since you are calling it from trusted code.

Comment: I have not personally used the Add-on Builder, but it states you can call the XPCOM APIs (which is what I am showing in the 2nd example) at the bottom of this page - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/sdk-vs-xul.html.