# How can a Firefox extension inject a local css file into a webpage?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I'm writing a Firefox extension that needs to inject a css file into webpages. The css file is bundled with the extension, so I can access it using a chrome url

```
chrome://extensionid/content/skin/style.css
```

I'm trying to inject css like this when the page is loaded:

```
var fileref = document.createElement("link");
fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
fileref.setAttribute("href", "chrome://extensionid/content/skin/style.css");
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
```

However, the css isn't loaded and Firebug shows 'Filtered chrome url' message instead of the file content, when I inspect the `link` element I created. If I try to load this css file from an external server, everything's fine.

Is there are way to load a css file bundled with the extension?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`resource:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Chrome_Registration#resource) instead of `chrome:`?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know of resource:. Looks like it's what I need.

Comment: I posted some background on why this is the right answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685243/inserting-css-with-a-firefox-extension/5395489#5395489

Comment: Can anyone confirm if Firefox still supports this access mechanism? I've spent hours on this and in all cases the latest version of Firefox refuses to allow page content to access items exposed with a resource alias in the manifest. Likewise, directly navigating to resource://alias/uri/to/file fails with no observable errors. If it still works, maybe a slightly more detailed example could resolve the confusion?

Comment: @JohnL I can confirm this works from Overlay addons. However in bootstrap addons resource is not supported by chrome.manifest so you have to do it programatically. [Mark Finkles Blog About Bootstrap Resource](http://starkravingfinkle.org/blog/2011/01/restartless-add-ons-more-resources/)

Comment: Thanks for the update Noitidart. In the end the problem I was running into was a bug in Firefox w/Firebug related to cache pollution or resource urls. If a failure to deliver a resource occurs and you correct the problem, it remains an issue indefinitely or until em:bootstrap is toggled. Very frustrating but too hard to write up a bug report and almost certainly wouldn't be accepted