# How to inject CSS located on /skin?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I want to inject a css file located on the skin folder in a browser page.

It is located on `chrome://orkutmanager/skin/om.css`, accessing manually show the file contents correctly.

I've [tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731736/how-can-a-firefox-extension-inject-a-local-css-file-into-a-webpage/2827707#2827707), but it's not working... What am I missing, or is it impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this workaround. Read the file then inject it's contents...

```
function Read(file)
{
    var ioService=Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"]
        .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService);
    var scriptableStream=Components
        .classes["@mozilla.org/scriptableinputstream;1"]
        .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIScriptableInputStream);

    var channel=ioService.newChannel(file,null,null);
    var input=channel.open();
    scriptableStream.init(input);
    var str=scriptableStream.read(input.available());
    scriptableStream.close();
    input.close();
    return str;
}

var style = $("<style type='text/css' />");
style.html(Read("chrome://orkutmanager/skin/om.css"));
$("head").append(style);
```

Comment: Just to clarify, did you try using "resource" as the answer on your link says (I ask because you linked to the question, not the answer, so I'm not completely sure what you're referring to by that.)

Comment: Yea, I tried the accepted solution over there, but it didn't work.

Comment: Interesting. The resource: uri worked for me, but now I'm worried that it might fail for some users. What version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: In that case, I would speculate that you did indeed mess up the resource URI somehow. On the other hand, if your way is working for you, I don't see much reason to change it now...

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [`nsIStyleSheetService`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIStyleSheetService):

```
loadCSS: function() {
     var sss = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/content/style-sheet-service;1"]
                .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIStyleSheetService);
     var ios = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"]
                .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService);
     var uri = ios.newURI("chrome://addon/skin/style.css", null, null);

     if(!sss.sheetRegistered(uri, sss.USER_SHEET))
         sss.loadAndRegisterSheet(uri, sss.USER_SHEET);
}
```

If you use `USER_SHEET`, the website's own CSS rules have higher priority than yours. Using `AGENT_SHEET`, your CSS should have higher priority.
In any way I needed to enforce some rules by using hte `!important` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731736/how-can-a-firefox-extension-inject-a-local-css-file-into-a-webpage/2827707#2827707) you referred to works if you reference the page document. In my case, using `gBrowser.contentDocument` worked.

```
var fileref = gBrowser.contentDocument.createElement("link");
fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
fileref.setAttribute("href", "resource://extensionid/content/skin/style.css");
gBrowser.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
```

Obviously make sure that you can access your css via the `resource://` protocol.