# Trying to create an iframe with svg src at my firefox extension

Tags: javascript, iframe, firefox-addon

I'm trying to make my extension create an iframe which its src tag direct to an svg file which is located at the extension files. something like `<iframe src="chrome://trail/content/onpagegui.svg"></iframe>`

Whenever I do it I get the following error: Security Error: Content at http://... may not load or link to chrome://trail/content/onpagegui.svg. (I think that's cause of the same origin policy)

I tried all kind of ways to solve this problem, among them I tried to use resource: instead of chrome: as suggested at [How can a Firefox extension inject a local css file into a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731736/how-can-a-firefox-extension-inject-a-local-css-file-into-a-webpage) but I can't make it work either cause I'm trying to embed an svg instead of a css or because I just don't get it... btw as much as I understood from MDC, resource: is for javascript codes and not css, am I right? is this solution workable?

I also tried to build the entire iframe and svg just by javascript, that cause tons of other issues to appear...

Is there any way to embed that .svg file into the newly created iframe?

Thanks a lot in advance,
Yonatan

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your extension [contentaccessible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/chrome_registration#contentaccessible).

Comment: Currently @ manifest.chrome I got the following line:
`
content     trail   chrome/content/     contentaccessible=yes
`
Sadly it doesn't work, I do know that the contentaccessible flag is being called correctly since I rely on it at other parts of my extension...

Comment: Ah, that's interesting, I didn't realise that contentaccessible didn't apply to frames. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possible solutions:

1. Use e.g. XMLHttpRequest to read your SVG into a string. Then set the src of the frame to a [data: URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data%3a_URL).
2. Register a component that implements [nsIAboutModule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIAboutModule). Then set the src of the frame to your [custom about: URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Custom_about%3a_URLs).

Ironically neither of these methods requires contentaccessible!

Comment: ok I had time only to test the first option and it works but only partially, from some reason the svg is getting loaded and work as supposed to but its css code is totally ignored... (everything is just black).

Oh btw, in order to read the SVG content into a string I used nsIScriptableInputStream instead of XMLHttpRequest, nothing wrong with that right?

Will test the second option asap and will let u know about the results (got some other things on my head as well...).

Comment: I just tried to implement your second suggestion but I keep failing to create an about: url (used the descriptions at the url u gave), more then that I found this thread http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=2014385&start=0 where the first reply state 
that this page is not for extensions at all (or am I misunderstanding something here?).
I actually want to make an about: url even for another issue at my extension.
thx again :)

Comment: OK I finally managed to make the about: url work (interesting enough I didn't do a thing.... extremely bizarre), anyhow it gives the same result as the first solution, the svg is getting loaded but only in black.... my guess is that it doesn't understand its doctype, though y not if it's basically the same file?

Comment: btw I found that setting the src to be the svg file at a remote server it work as it should (http://...). very bizarre...

Comment: Accessing remote SVG has fewer concerns since the developers are more used to dealing with remote sites trying to access content from other remote sites, and therefore are more likely to try to get things to work safely rather than blocking content to play safe.

Comment: Oh well... thanks a lot for helping anyway :)
Will update this post if I'll find the answer